# I need to create a "map" of 0s and 1s

Tags: math, pseudocode

I know this is not much of a question but a seek of help, but I wanted to give it a shot too since I'm really blocked with this.

I want to create a sort of map (representend by a string) that is filled with numbers in a way similar to this example:

```
000000000000000000
001111000000011000
011111100000111110
000111110001111100
000011000000011000
000000000000000000
```

So the idea is that 0 would be like "nothing" or imagine this is a world map and 0s are grass tiles while 1s could be for example ground tiles.

I want to be able to generate something like that (on a bigger scale) with lots of small and big patches of "ground". But obviously it can't just be random 1s and 0s everywhere as it wouldn't look natural, it has to be somewhat natural looking shapes.

My maths are just too bad to think of a way to achieve this out of my head,
I'm not asking for the code, just seeking some help.
If you guys could point me in the right direction it would help a lot :)

Comment: So you want clusters. How about you start with random 1's and 0's, and then any symbol surrounded by four of the "other" gets converted? Or maybe you start with two or three 1's in a sea of 0's, and they grow? There are *many* ways to do it, and you're the only one who can judge whether the results look "natural" to you.

Comment: That was one of my ideas, could work but if the size of the map is too big then the whole process would take quite some time if I have to constatly loop on the 1s over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to generate this for fun, you might be looking for ascii art generator. There are lot of online tools available, just a search away for the phrase `ascii art generator`.

Answer (score 0):

Background: Every image is made up of pixels. Every one of these pixels have a color defined by (R,G,B) with each component ranging from 0-255.

Defined Problem: You want to convert each pixel of an image to 0 or 1 based on their color. Color would be the defining attribute here as we expect the 0 attribute and 1 attribute to be visually different.

Solution: You'll need to create a function which will map each pixel of an image based on their RGB values to either 0 or 1. You'll have to classify ranges for them according to which every pixel will either be converted to a 0 or 1 as per their weight.

Implementation: I'll probably be looking towards Python Libraries. There are tons of them and I'm certain there must be one to access an image at a bit level. When you have the number of pixels in length and width, use those parameters to construct an array of that size and loop your function over the image pixels and go on filling the results in the array.

Crude Way: You can alternatively visit this website which will do it for you. Just in case you want it done at the easiest way possible: https://www.text-image.com/convert/ 
There are many more like this if you search for them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an algorithm you could probably start with all 0s. Then randomly and sparsely place some 1s into the field. Now take each of the placed 1s and randomly select a direction (up, down, left, right) and a number *n* of steps between 0 and a small number *m*, e.g. 3. Let the selected 1 "grow" in that direction *n* times. i.e. cover the *n* spots in that direction with 1s. Repeat for any newly placed 1s (maybe omit those which were already placed over previously existing 1s) until no newly placed 1 is unprocessed. That should at least give you some "connected patches", maybe similar to plants e.g. grass might spread. And maybe play with *m* a little, to vary the size of the "patches".

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for,
I'll do it with Perlin Noise :)